# Wordpress Password-Protection Not Working with Filtered Content

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with a third-party theme and am trying to use the built-in Wordpress password-protection for pages. However, the theme runs the content through several filters. Therefore the password-protection doesn't work because the_content() isn't used:

```
$custom_theme_main_color = "#".get_option('theme_style_color');
$content = str_replace( '__USE_THEME_MAIN_COLOR__', $custom_theme_main_color, $content );
theme_content_shortcoder($content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
if (function_exists('wpb_js_remove_wpautop') == true)
    echo wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content);
else echo wp_kses_post($content); 
$shortcodes_custom_css = get_post_meta( $theme_thisPostID, '_wpb_shortcodes_custom_css', true );
if ( isset($shortcodes_custom_css) && ! empty( $shortcodes_custom_css ) ) {
    theme_set_custom_inline_css($shortcodes_custom_css);
}
```

Is it possible to apply the password-protection here? I'd prefer not to use a third-party plugin.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to rework this to use the_content() so that the WP password form is displayed?